# How to integrate from t to T with respect to u, basic integration

Tags: integration

Could someone show me how to do this? Im getting confused with wrt t or u

$\int_t^T e^{-k(u-t)} du$

Comment: $e^{kt}\int_t^{T} e^{-ku}du=\frac1  k e^{kt}(e^{-kt}-e^{-kT})$.

Answer (score 1):

Separating the exponential into two parts, we have:
\begin{align*}
\int_t^Te^{-k(u-t)}\,du &= e^{kt}\int_t^Te^{-ku}\,du \\
&= e^{kt}\times -\frac{1}{k}e^{-ku}\bigg|_t^T \\
&= \frac{1}{k}e^{kt}\times \left(-e^{-kT}+e^{-kt}\right) \\
&= \frac1k(1-e^{k(t-T)}).
\end{align*}